# AS3 Returning a variable from an event listener function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to return XML from an event complete back to the main function, but can't figure out how to do it.

Here's the functions I'm calling:

Main File:

```
public var mySendAndLoad:SendAndLoad = new SendAndLoad(); 

mySendAndLoad.sendData(url,variables)
```

The mySendAndLoad class:

```
package 
{

    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.xml.XMLDocument;

    public class SendAndLoad
    {
        public var xml:XML = new XML();
        public var xmlList:XMLList;

        public function SendAndLoad()
        {
        }
        public function sendData(url:String, _vars:URLVariables):String
        {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            request.data = _vars;
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
            loader.load(request);
        }
        private function handleComplete(event:Event):String
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
            xml = XML(loader.data);
            xmlList = xml.children();
            return(xmlList[1]);
        }
        private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace("Error loading URL.");
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is have the xmlList come back to the main file. But since it isn't in the event I called (sendData) it doesn't get brought back.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package 
{

import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.xml.XMLDocument;

//THIS CLASS EXTENDS EVENTDISPATCHER SO IT CAN DISPATCH EVENTS
public class SendAndLoad extends EventDispatcher
{
    public var xml:XML = new XML();
    public var xmlList:XMLList;

    public function SendAndLoad()
    {
        super(null);
    }
    public function sendData(url:String, _vars:URLVariables):void
    {
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        request.data = _vars;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        loader.load(request);
    }
    private function handleComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
        xml = XML(loader.data);
        xmlList = xml.children();


        //NEW CODE
        var evt:Event=new Event(Event.COMPLETE);
        dispatchEvent(evt);
        //return(xmlList[1]);
    }
    private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        trace("Error loading URL.");
    }
}
```

}

and in the main file

```
public var mySendAndLoad:SendAndLoad = new SendAndLoad(); 
mySendAndLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadCompleted);
mySendAndLoad.sendData(url,variables)

private function xmlLoadCompleted(e:Event):void {
    var childToUse:XML=mySendAndLoad.xmlList[1];
    //whatever else you want to do 
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tried using this code in my own project. However, Flash is reporting an error for the public function sendData, saying it does not return a value. I tried setting the function to :void, but it still says the same error. Any help on this? Thanks

Comment: @MrPablo, whoa, I can't believe nobody caught that error for so long. I've edited the answer (changing the function to void) and it works correctly. I'd suggest you clean the project (if you're using Flash Builder) or restart Flash Pro and retry

Comment: Yea, I figure it out not long after posting my comment!

Answer (score 0):

Without serious modifications you have two options:

1. Your `SaveAndLoad` class to derrive EventDispatcher and send a custom event with the data in it.
2. More clean/non obtrusive is to make `sendData` method modifications:

   ```
   public function sendData(url:String, _vars:URLVariables, resultHandler:Function=null):String
   {
       loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, resultHandler);
   }
   ```

You can pass a function defined in your main file, still have the ability to attach inner listeners for whatever you want in `SaveAndLoad` class, and you will have your data.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but what would I put in the main file?

Comment: in you main file you define a function:
private function handleLoadComplete(event:Event):void
{

}
and when calling your your mySendAndLoad.sendData(url,variables)
you just call mySendAndLoad.sendData(url,variables, handleLoadComplete) .
You attach a listener to the loader, the handler of which is reference to your function defined in the main file.

Answer (score 0):

Just dispatch an event

```
package 
{

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.xml.XMLDocument;

    public class SendAndLoad extend Sprite
    {
        public var xml:XML = new XML();
        public var xmlList:XMLList;

        public function SendAndLoad()
        {
        }
        public function sendData(url:String, _vars:URLVariables):String
        {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            request.data = _vars;
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
            loader.load(request);
        }
        private function handleComplete(event:Event):String
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
            xml = XML(loader.data);
            xmlList = xml.children();


           // return(xmlList[1]);
           this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'ONDATA' ) );
        }
        private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace("Error loading URL.");
        }
    }
}


// usage
var sender:SendAndLoad = new SendAndLoad( );
sender.addEventListener( 'ONDATA', myXMLLoaded);
sender.sendData( url, _vars )

function myXMLLoaded( e:Event ):void{
  trace(sender.xml);
}
```

Comment: As you see by my posted code the return statement is commented out. Instead you this.dispatchEvent( event );  Now in the main class where created the object var sender:SendAndLoad = new SendAndLoad( );
 you will add an event listener. sender.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myXMLLoaded);
in the function myXMLLoaded you can now access the data onthe var that you assigned it to sender.xml. Does this help?

Comment: If you still don't understand I will need you to edit your question and post the code where you are creating the SendAndLoad
 Object.

Comment: Even if we stay away from the fact that the class SaveAndLoad isn't an EventDispatcher derived (a.k.a. cannot dispatch events), this technique won't work since after you re-dispatch the event the <code>target</code> of the event won't be the loader but the SaveAndLoad intance.

Comment: I'm getting an "undefined method dispatchEvent through static type SendAndLoad" error with that.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `dispatchEvent`;

first declare to it

```
public class personal_info extends EventDispatcher { }
```

and you must define listener into that class

```
   dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you must declare variable such as public
public var variable:String;

You must use dispatchEvent;

first declare to it
   public class personal_info extends EventDispatcher {
   ...

and you must define listener into that complete event
   variable = "variable";
   dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
   ...

And you must call just like calling normal event in another class
   var sample:SampleClass = new SampleClass ();
   sample.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , cComplete);

And you can use that variable in this class like:
  private fonction (e:Event):void {
    trace (e.target.variable);
}
```